# Operator precedence change

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

The following used to build OK on VS2008 but on VS2013, it moans.  OK in g++.

```
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    int a = 2, b = 5;
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << a == 0 ? a : b;
}
```

The error message is

```
1>u:\precedence\precedence.cpp(7): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\exception(497): could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\exception(502): or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\exception(507): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\system_error(402): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\system_error(410): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, int)'
```

It works on both versions if the output statement is changed to

```
    oss << (a == 0? a: b);
```

I can force a different error in VS2008 if a constant is not used: something like

```
int zero = 0;
oss << a == zero? a: b;
```

Just wondering why there is an error when a constant is not used.

*Edit* Managed to get an warning with g++ with -Wall.

Comment: I always use lots of brackets with `?` because it can be funny.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. There's a minimal example with a full error message and it's perfectly answerable, and not trivial. These kinds of bugs do happen, despite unnecessary parentheses usually being a decent idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression the compiler sees due to the precedence is, in all cases:

```
((oss << a) == 0) ? a : b;
```

Now `oss << a` returns `oss`. How can you compare `oss` with 0? It has an implicit conversion operator `operator void *`.

VS2013 presumably replaced that with `explicit operator bool` for C++11 (the whole point of which was so that these hard-to-find bugs don't occur). libstdc++ has not done this replacement to my knowledge. It must in order to conform with C++11.

Now why doesn't `zero` compile? `zero` is not a null pointer constant, but `0` is. Thus, the latter can be compared to the pointer returned by `operator void *`.

In any case, the simple way to fix this so it should work properly with any conforming implementation is to add parentheses:

```
oss << (a == 0 ? a : b);
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the compiler is interpreting it different.

Based on the error, I would suspect that the compiler is interpreting the line of code like this

`(oss << a) == 0 ? a : b;`

So when you put in the parens there was no longer any way it could interpret it that way, and you got the expected results.
I suspect that this would also work.

`oss << (a == 0) ? a : b;`

Comment: By different, I meant 2008 vs 2013, since they were stating that it worked in the prior, but not the later.